# What is CPU_STATE_MAX?

Tags: c, macos, unix, mach

What is the `CPU_STATE_MAX` macro and what is it used for? I couldn't find any descriptive/relevant google results or man pages.

I am on Mac OSX Snowleopard, if that makes any difference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Questions about some unix code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767504/questions-about-some-unix-code)

Comment: @HansPassant I already checked the link provided by the answer to the question and couldnt find a reference to CPU_STATE_MAX, which is why I asked this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/ident?v=xnu-792.6.70;im=bigexcerpts;i=CPU_STATE_USER)--it corresponds to the number of CPU states defined in the `machine.h` header.  These different states are then used to index different pieces of information about the CPU state, which can differ by CPU state--idle, 'nice', etc.